# Google Sheets API - Formatting inserted values

Tags: python, google-sheets-api

Through this code I've update a bunch of rows in Google Spreadsheet.
The request goes well and returns me the `updatedRange` below.

```
result = service.spreadsheets().values().append(
    spreadsheetId=spreadsheetId,
    range=rangeName,
    valueInputOption="RAW",
    insertDataOption="INSERT_ROWS",
    body=body
).execute()
print(result)
print("Range updated")
updateRange = result['updates']['updatedRange']
```

Now I would like to do a `batchUpdate` request to set the formatting or set a protected range, but those API require a range specified as `startRowIndex`, `endRowIndex` and so on.

How could I retrieve the rows index from the `updatedRange`?

Comment: I'm not sure if there is a way to retrieve row/column indexes from the `updatedRange`. What I can suggest is to create a function that will count the rows and columns based on the `updatedRange` value. As the document : [Updating Spreadsheets](https://developers.google.com/sheets/guides/batchupdate) stated, "there are a number of different ways to achieve the same result." But if you feel that this is feature will help, try filing it [here](https://code.google.com/a/google.com/p/apps-api-issues/issues/entry?template=Feature%20request&labels=Type-Enhancement,API-Tasks).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Waiting for a native or better answer, I'll post a function I've created to translate a `namedRange` into a `gridRange`.
The function is far from perfect and does not translate the sheet name to a sheet id (I left that task to another specific function), but accept named ranges in the form:

- `sheet!A:B`
- `sheet!A1:B`
- `sheet!A:B5`
- `sheet!A1:B5`

Here is the code

```
    import re

    def namedRange2Grid(self, rangeName):
        ascii_uppercase = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
        match = re.match(".*?\!([A-Z0-9]+)\:([A-Z0-9]+)", rangeName)
        if match:
            start = match.group(1)
            end = match.group(2)
            matchStart = re.match("([A-Z]{1,})([1-9]+){0,}", start)
            matchEnd = re.match("([A-Z]{1,})([1-9]+){0,}", end)
            if matchStart and matchEnd:
                GridRange = {}
                letterStart = matchStart.group(1)
                letterEnd = matchEnd.group(1)
                if matchStart.group(2):
                    numberStart = int(matchStart.group(2))
                    GridRange['startRowIndex'] = numberStart - 1
                if matchEnd.group(2):
                    numberEnd = int(matchEnd.group(2))
                    GridRange['endRowIndex'] = numberEnd

                i = 0
                for l in range(0, len(letterStart)):
                    i = i + (l * len(ascii_uppercase))
                    i = i + ascii_uppercase.index(letterStart[l])
                GridRange['startColumnIndex'] = i

                i = 0
                for l in range(0, len(letterEnd)):
                    i = i + (l * len(ascii_uppercase))
                    i = i + ascii_uppercase.index(letterEnd[l])
                GridRange['endColumnIndex'] = i + 1

                return GridRange
```